# How to use jQueryUI on Blogger

Tags: jquery-ui

How to add jQueryUI plugin to my Blogger (Blogspot) site?

I know I can download it and use it offline, but (as far as I know), you can't upload separate files to Blogspot, so I can't call them with `src`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download it for offline purpose, but for online purpose you particularly don't have to upload it somewhere. You can use online jQuery libraries direclty and add this snippet code in the footer (Recommended)  or header area of the template as per your requirements.

jQuery on Google APIS

Snippet: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

note: 1.2.5 and 1.2.4 are not hosted due to their short and unstable lives in the wild.
jQuery UI on Google APIS

Snippet: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`

note: This library depends on jQuery. You must also load jQuery before loading this module. Version 1.8.3 is not hosted due to its short life, and the alias 1.8.3 actually loads 1.8.4.

OR

Add this code from their official web:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the custom gadget facility on the blogspot.com site in  which you can easily use   the  javascript and jquery  code  in one file .

Answer (score 0):

Upload somewhere else, or just link it from google hosted libraries,

https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery-ui